# xpath simplexml tags query and how to get node values

Tags: php, simplexml

I have my xpath query using simpleXML which I want to use to get the node values of the tags title,description and link. But I don't know how to output them like only outputting the title contents for instance.

```
<item>
   <title>Cell Phone Plans That Make You Go Hmmm</title> 
   <link>http://www.articlegeek.com/computers/telecommunication_articles/10574-    cellphoneplanst.htm</link> 
   <description>Cell phone plans across the globe vary a great deal. Some say that cell phone plans in the US are more costly. However, there are some advantages to the cell phone plans in the US which may balance the difference.</description> 
</item> 

function xmlXpath()
{
    $xml = xmlParse();

    $userIN = "cell";
    $nodesT = $xml->xpath("
       //*
       [
           text()
           [
               contains(
                   translate(.,'ABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                               'abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),
                   '".$userIN."'
               )
           ]
       ]
    ");
    return $nodesT;
}
```

Comment: please post your XML-code in your question, not as link.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** considering your xpath, do:

```
foreach ($nodesT as $nodeT) echo "$nodeT <br />";
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/WKDfvJ

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to show the xml so I linked the site where it is instead.

Comment: @DOWmad: simple copy it into your question and indent it like code.